# Grocery Crud display image from another table

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I am trying to display a image in grocery crud edit from another table. Have provided the relation it is just displaying the file name and not the image.
Below is my code let me know where I need to correct. Also don't want to update the image in my edit table (inwardinventory). just need to display it based on selection of sacoskucode column from mastersku table.

```
            public function entry()
                {
                        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

                        //$crud->set_theme('datatables');
                        $crud->unset_delete();

                        $crud->set_table('inwardinventory');
                        $crud->set_primary_key('SacoSku','inwardinventory');
                        $crud->set_relation('SacoSku','mastersku','SacoSku');
                        $crud->set_relation('PdtImage','mastersku','PdtImage');
                        $crud->set_field_upload('PdtImage','assets/uploads/files');
                        $crud->set_subject('In Out Stock');
                        $crud->field_type('TranscationType','dropdown',
                        array('IN' => 'Inward / Purchase','OUT' => 'Out Ward / Sale / Basement'));
                        $output = $crud->render();

                        $this->_example_output($output);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide tables structure with the question to give you exactly the answer;

- according to the documentation of grocery crud website the set_relation function
  accept the parameters:

> `set_relation($field_name ,$related_table,$related_title_field)`

if your database schema  like this:

```
tblOne(id, refImageID)
```

the set relation function must be like this:

```
$crud->set_relation('refImageID','tblImage','imagePath');
```

- to avoid edit amage and just display it add the line

`$crud->fields(array("feilds", "to", "edit"));`